# clGetEventProfilingInfo() bug in MacOSX?

Tags: c, macos, opencl

The several clGet*Info OpenCL functions allow to either (a) obtain the size of the required information, or (b) the information itself. This is required in several cases, such as getting the name of a device:

```
char* name;
size_t size_of_name;
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 0, NULL, &size_of_name);
name = (char*) malloc(size_of_name);
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, size_of_name, name, NULL);
```

All of the clGet*Info OpenCL functions follow this pattern. However, I found that this doesn't work for the clGetEventProfilingInfo() in MacOSX. When I try to get the size, e.g.:

```
clGetEventProfilingInfo(evt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, 0, NULL, &info_size);
```

I get an error -30 (CL_INVALID_VALUE), although the implementation returns 8 bytes in the info_size variable. Here is a small complete example of this behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACOSX)
    #include <OpenCL/OpenCL.h>
#else
    #include <CL/opencl.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    cl_platform_id platf;
    cl_device_id dev;
    cl_int status;
    cl_uint a_buffer[1024];
    cl_mem buf_dev = NULL;
    cl_command_queue cq = NULL;
    cl_event evt = NULL;
    cl_context ctx = NULL;
    cl_ulong t_start, t_end;
    size_t info_size;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) a_buffer[i] = (i * 7) % 100;

    status = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platf, NULL);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clGetDeviceIDs(platf, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &dev, NULL);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    ctx = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &dev, NULL, NULL, &status);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    cq = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, dev, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &status);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    buf_dev = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 1024*sizeof(cl_uint),
        NULL, &status);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cq, buf_dev, CL_TRUE, 0,
        1024*sizeof(cl_uint), a_buffer, 0, NULL, &evt);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clFinish(cq);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clGetEventProfilingInfo(evt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, 0, NULL, &info_size);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clGetEventProfilingInfo(evt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, info_size, &t_start, NULL);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clGetEventProfilingInfo(evt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, 0, NULL, &info_size);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    status = clGetEventProfilingInfo(evt, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, info_size, &t_end, NULL);
    if (status) { printf("%d\n", status); exit(-1);}

    printf("Total time (ns): %lu\n", (unsigned long) (t_end - t_start));

    clReleaseEvent(evt);
    clReleaseMemObject(buf_dev);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(cq);
    clReleaseContext(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine in Linux and Windows with several different OpenCL implementations. In MacOSX I get the invalid value error.

I know the clGetEventProfilingInfo() function always returns information of size cl_ulong, however I'm doing this in a automatic fashion, such that the size is always requested before
the information in order to allocate memory for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run your example code on my own OS X system and get the same results. Interestingly, the `info_size` output variable is populated with the correct value (8 bytes), despite the resulting error code.

This is definitely a bug - the specification states that `clGetEventProfilingInfo` should only return `CL_INVALID_VALUE` for `param_value_size` if `param_value` is not `NULL` (the same as all the other `clGet*Info` functions, as you point out).

You can report bugs like this to Apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Thanks, I got my sanity back ;) I'll report the bug.